# Android notification with images in collapsed mode

Tags: android, android-notifications

I recently saw a YouTube notification with image shown in the collapsed view of the notification.

Now i know and already use BigPictureStyle of the notification to show images inside the notification when it gets expanded. But when using this mode, the collapsed notification only shows summary text and not the small thumbnail of the image.

YouTube notifications show the thumbnail of the image in collapsed mode and the usual big picture style large image when expanded. This isn't the big icon either as when the notification gets expanded, the big icon is the YouTube channel thumbnail and the image is shown in the big picture portion.

How would i go about achieving something like this? Is this a custom remote view which expands into a big picture view?

I don't know how to even go about doing this. My current code is:

```
            try{

               NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,UserRewardChannel);

                builder.setAutoCancel(true);

                builder.setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("messagetitle"));

                builder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("messagebody"));

                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_foodini_notif);
                builder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorAccent));

                builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher2));

                Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

                builder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);

                builder.setVibrate(new long[]{0,100,100,100});

                if(Boolean.parseBoolean(remoteMessage.getData().get("hasimage"))){

                    Bitmap image=null;

                    Response response = null;

                    try {

                        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                                .connectTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                                .readTimeout(10000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                                .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
                                .build();

                        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                                .url(remoteMessage.getData().get("imageurl"))
                                .build();

                        response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                        InputStream imageStream = response.body().byteStream();

                        image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        //Log.d("FragmentCreate","Some error occured while creating the notification in debug mode",e);
                    }finally {
                        try {
                            response.close();
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            //Do nothing
                        }
                    }

                    if(image!=null){
                        builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(image).setSummaryText(remoteMessage.getData().get("messagebody")));

                    }else{
                        builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().setSummaryText(remoteMessage.getData().get("messagebody")).bigText(remoteMessage.getData().get("messagebody")));
                    }

                }else{
                    builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().setSummaryText(remoteMessage.getData().get("messagebody")).bigText(remoteMessage.getData().get("messagebody")));
                }

                int notif_id=(int)(System.currentTimeMillis()%10000);

                NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());

                notificationManagerCompat.notify(notif_id,builder.build());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                //Log it
            }
```

[image: preview of the youtube notification]

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Comment: Afraid not :( it's unfortunate that they never put this in their documentation...

Comment: I also want to know

Comment: hey How to show image as shown in above picture edge to edge?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create custom notification layout. The guidelines on How to create these are at:

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification

The code at this link describes how you can set small and expanded layout of the notification